# Why doesnt SQLite Work In Ionic 2 After Installing Plugin

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic2

I have installed the ionic 2 sqlite plugin for an application and when i run it in my browser i am warned i tried to access sqlite but its not installed. Other ionic native plugins just warn i tried to access whatever plugin but cordova is not installed, which is a perfect warning because cordova plugins dont work with the browser, but i dont know whey the sqlite warning keeps saying its not installed.

When i run this application on my android device, it truly shows sqlite isnt installed.

I have tried, removing the plugin and adding it again but to no avail. I dont know why its not working.

Comment: is the plugin present in your plugins folder? and also is an entry present in **config.xml**?

Comment: No it isn't present

Comment: Try to install plugin with `-save`option